Simple yet un-solvable algorithm
I have tried writing an algorithm which will solve the problem:
"Consider the set $X:= \{0,...,14\}$. Define the 'blocks' of $X$ to be the 4-element subsets of $X$. For each block, let all the distinct pairs of points within the block be 'points'. Your task is to select at least one point from each block, such that you select no more than 5 points from any block." Also you are not allowed to brute force it.
My algorithms so far have tried "minimizing intersections" (with blocks that have already been chosen from) approach, and also "minimizing forbidden point" approach, where I call a "forbidden point" a point in a block such that you have already selected the other 5. The best one so far was the "minimizing intersection" approach where the tie-breaker (intersections equal) minimized forbidden points. I got it down to only 2 blocks that I didn't select from.
What is the "optimal" algorithmic approach here? I am trying to do something like Dijkstra's algorithm, but I think I am taking sub-optimal paths. Should I be considering averages of pairs using some kind of probability model?

Where did you encounter this task?  Please credit the original source, as per our rules: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

I don't understand the problem statement.  What prevents you from picking 5 points arbitrarily from each block?  or 1 arbitrarily from each block?  If you pick 1 from each block, you haven't picked more than 5, right?  Are you implying that you pick some set of points, and then for each point, count how many blocks it is contained in?

"you are not allowed to brute force it" is not a meaningful requirement.  There are any number of ways to build an algorithm that isn't obviously doing brute force, but might be doing a disguised form of brute force.  How would you tell them apart?  If you have rejected brute force, presumably it violates some requirement you might have (e.g., that it be feasible to run within your lifetime).  Please think about what that requirement might be, then replace "you are not allowed" with that particular requirement.

@D.W. because of overlap.... clearly if you decide its a good idea to select 5 from some number of blocks eventually the overlapping blocks will generate a block containing 6 selected points

let all the distinct pairs of points within the block be 'points'  uses points in two different meanings: please check and resolve, if possible.

(I missed the closing quotation mark more than once - I much prefer a block quote, see post editor help. And remember to tell who created the problem statement and where you found it.)

Algorithm: In a block containing four numbers 0 <= a < b < c < d <= 14, define dist(x,y) as y - x modulo 15 when x < y. Select a point x, y with maximum distance out of the four points (a,b), (b,c), (c, d), (d, a) and if this leaves two or more candidates then pick any of them.
Since the sum of the four distances is 15, the largest distance cannot be <= 3. So the largest distance is >= 4, which means at least one distance is <= 3. We will never select a point with distance <= 3, so of the six possible points in a block one will never be selected.
PS: This solves the problem if d < k where k = 15. A very similar argument shows it works if k is not a multiple of 4. If k = 16 and we have multiple points with the same distance 4 we take the one with the smallest x. Next there is no need for blocks to be all subsets of a block, and to be integers. So
Let a block be a set of 4 real numbers 0 <= a < b < c < d, then pick k > the largest d, define dist (x, y) = (y - x) modulo k as before and the algorithm gives a solution.

One approach is to use integer linear programming. Introduce a 0-or-1 variable $x_{i,j}$ for each point (i.e., each pair $i,j$), which will be 1 if it is selected.  For each block, you obtain two linear inequalities, namely, $1 \le \sum x_{i,j} \le 5$ where $i,j$ ranges over all points in the block.  Use an off-the-shelf ILP solver to find any feasible solution.  This has 105 variables and 2730 linear inequalities, so it might be solvable by an off-the-shelf ILP solver.
